# Laravel Isset errors displaying []

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, isset

why evertime I the load the page isset does not load properly its still show to the page an array like this
[] ?

Views

```
@if(isset($errors))
{{$errors}}
@endif
```

Controller

```
 $data = Input::all();

if($errors = $this->deliveryReport->isInvalid($data))
{
    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($errors);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the most common use of a collection presentation:

```
@if($collection->isEmpty())
    <h2>No items were found</h2>
@else
    <h2>The following {{$collection->count()}} items were found</h2>
    @foreach($collection as $c)
        {{ $c->someAttribute }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Now specifically for `$errors`:

```
@if($errors->any())
    <div id="error-box">
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <div>{{ $error }}</div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```

Remember to pass correctly `$errors` to your view after the validation has done its job. So in your controller:

```
$rules = [...];

$v = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

if($v->fails())
{
    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($v);
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

withError() make it instance of [MessageBag](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.MessageBag.html), you can use methods on it:

```
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    {{ $error }}
@endforeach
```

or see the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#working-with-error-messages)